# Parsing HATEOAS JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, gson, hateoas

I have the following HATEOAS style JSON response:

```
{
    "count": 37,
    "next": "https://swapi.co/api/species/?page=2",
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
         ...
    ]
}
```

I have to read all results from that endpoint, however, only way to this is to go through pages, they don't provide any endpoint with the whole result as one page.

My idea to solve this is to simply get next field from the response and repeat until `"next"` is not null.

Is there a better way offered in Java or Gson?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the total(`count=37; total=100;...`) number of element then you can fetch the result simply by pagination. As we can see only the `previous` and `next` field are provided so you have to fetch `next` until its value become `null`. Java or Gson has nothing to do with it, all it depends on how much information you are getting from backend.

> My idea to solve this is to simply get next field from the response and repeat until "next" is not null.

**Your approach seems legit.**

Answer (score -1):

Unless you can't provide a query param like limit or something similar to that, I feel like this would not be possible. As ruhul stated, your approach seems good.